# Is 50 min connector in Helsinki enough

Tags: us-citizens, layovers, helsinki

JFK -> HEL 10:01 AM (50 min) HEL (11:00) -> CPH Copenhagen.

All flight booked through American Airlines operated by fin air.

Is this enough since I am staying in the Schengen region?

Comment: You are not “staying in the Schengen region”, but actually entering it in HEL.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a single ticket, the answer is "the airline is highly confident that you can make this connection".

No connection is ever "guaranteed" but the chances of you making it are very high and if you don't the airline will have to take care of you (rebook for free, potentially provide hotel and/or meals, pay delay compensation, etc.)

One tip: if you check luggage your chances of they waiting for you are a little higher, since they have to unload the bags if you are not on the plane. Of course that only helps if only you are late (e.g. snagged in a long immigration line) but not your bags.